Reference Request: Proof of 14 bravais lattices
One can view the classic crystallography from a mathematical aspect as follows:
A point group of $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is $\{\tau\in\mathrm{O}(n)\mid\tau\Omega=\Omega\}$.
A lattice in $\mathbb R^n$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$, i.e., a group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$.
Assume $L_1,L_2\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ are lattices. If the point groups of $L_1,L_2$ are conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$, then we say $L_1,L_2$ are in the same Bravais class.
This question has mentioned the Jordan-Zassenhaus theorem which asserts there are finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$. Thus there are finitely many Bravais classes.

However, the proof of Jordan-Zassenhaus is not such constructive (at least for the proof I know). How to jump from preceding math aspects to usual physics aspects like primitive and centering lattices?
I didn't see anyone on Internet leaving references for this. Maybe it's intuitive to understand but how can we prove it?

here are some course notes from Seoul National https://ocw.snu.ac.kr/sites/default/files/NOTE/W06-Bravais.pdf

I find it in Miller's Symmetry groups and their applications, where the author discusses completely how these 14 Bravais lattices are induced and distinct.
In short, we need the following proposition:

If the lattice point group contains a subgroup $C_n$ for $n=3,4,6$, then it also contains a subgroup $C_{nv}$.

Combine this result with "every lattice point group contains inversion". We know only these point groups can be lattice point groups:
$$
S_2,\,C_{2h},\,D_{2h},\,D_{3d},\,D_{4h},\,D_{6h},\,O_h.
$$
Then the author dive into each case to verify the result.

cubic system $O_h$ : primitive + face-centered + body-centered
hexagonal system $D_{6h}$ : primitive
tetragonal system $D_{4h}$ : primitive + body-centered
rhombohedral system $D_{3d}$ : primitive
orthorhombic system $D_{2h}$ : primitive + base-centered + body-centered + face-centered
monoclinic system $C_{2h}$ : primitive + base-centered
triclinic system $S_2$ : primitive

Summarize all to get 14 Bravais lattices.
